# WinJS render listView in a table

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

I am working on HTML/JS Win8 store app. I would like to render ListView in a table. How would I achieve this?

For now I have something like that:

```
        <table id="products">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                </tr>
                <tr data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template" id="productsRowTemplate">
                    <td data-win-bind="textContent: name"></td>
                    <td data-win-bind="textContent: description"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div id="productsListView"
            data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
            data-win-bind="winControl.itemDataSource: products.dataSource;"
            data-win-options="{ 
            itemTemplate: select('#productsRowTemplate'), 
            layout: { type: WinJS.UI.ListLayout }
            }">
        </div>
```

However, the result is not what I expect at all:
http://postimg.org/image/4z39tvu9v/

I would like to achieve effect similar to this one (I used styling from that example in my view):
http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_table_fancy

The reason why I use listView is that I am working with ViewModels which expose collections via properties - I just want to bind data to the view and show it using specific template. I would definately not want to create table dynamically from view's code behind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal is to render a table, the ListView is not what you want. The key thing is to separate the idea of the collection--your data source--from the control that you use to present it. That's why there's a WinJS.Binding.List collection class and a WinJS.UI.ListView control as separate entities.

A table is one way to present a collection; a ListView is another. So it doesn't really make sense to try to combine the two. In your markup, the template elements will actually be removed from the DOM and not render in the table. The ListView will attempt to use that template to render itself, but as it generates <tr> and <td> elements within its own div (outside of a <table>) it won't really work. That is, the template gets rendered for each item in the data source as children of the div where you declare the ListView, not at the place where you declare the template.

Although you could declare the ListView as a child of the table, it won't quite work there either because the ListView creates a deep div structure below the element where you declare it.

So count the ListView out for this purpose. What you want instead is a simple custom control that can take a WinJS.Binding.List and render a template as direct children of that control. In Windows 8.1 Preview there is a new control called the Repeater that serves this exact purpose, and the [HTML Repeater control sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/HTML-Repeater-control-da22d278) demonstrates it in the context of a <table>. Note that you'll want to use a <thead> for your headings and declare the control on the <tbody> so it can render copies of the template that has <tr> as the root element.

If you're targeting Windows 8 you won't have the Repeater, of course, but it's not too complicated to create one of your own (borrowing from the Win8.1 Repeater sources if you want). Define a constructor with WinJS.Class.define and make sure you have options through which you can declaratively specify the data source and the template. The template would contain your data-win-bind attributes. In the controls' constructor, iterate through the Binding.List, rendering a copy of template for each item in the list. Then call WinJS.Binding.processAll with the root element of that item and the item from the data source, which will set up the data binding you want.

You'd declare this control again on the tbody element so it creates tr children in the right place. To use the Repeater example (where it uses an inline template):

```
<table class="table">
  <thead class="table-header"><tr><td>Id</td><td>Description</td></tr></thead>
    <tbody class="table-body"
      data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Repeater" data-win-options="{data: Data.items}">
      <tr class="table-body-row">
          <td data-win-bind="textContent: id"></td>
          <td data-win-bind="textContent: description"></td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In the end you are creating the table dynamically, but it's encapsulated in the control so you can set up the data binding relationships declaratively.

Comment: Thank you for a thorough answer. The reason why I was trying to use ListView is that I was trying to achieve something similar to mentioned by you Repeater control (list of items templated as table rows). Thanks to your answer I now understand why my approach was invalid.